# My angular production-level project on refresh shows 401 then 200 simultaneously when i reload "my-subscription" page

Tags: angular-ui-router

The project is running client-side(csr) and server-side(ssr) on the same time, when i am logged in then visit my-subscription page, reload the page it redirects me to login form but immediately redirects me again to the right path (/my-subscription), also when i inspect networks i see  2 requests response 401 and 200[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/5FP4z.png)

The token is stored in both local storage and cookies ( i know it's not meant to be like that) but one of them the header comes empty (ssr) that's why i get 401 and the other (csr) i get 200.
ps: sorry but i'm not an expert in angular but i searched for a solution but i didn't find on the internet